# Bootstrap not working locally

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm having an issue when attempting to use Bootstrap locally. I have tried the exact same code on JsFiddle and other online editors, works beautifully. However when I migrate the code into my Brackets IDE instance nothing is working. I would appreciate if someone would shed some light on the situation. Below I've attached a small snippet.

Note : styling works, like whenever I classify a  as a panel the style changes. The issue I'm having is where style changes are related. Example btn-group with radio / toggle buttons, whenever I click on something nothing happens.

```
<html>

<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css"></link>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css"></link>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap-theme.css.map"></link>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css.map"></link>
    <script src="bootstrap/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
    <script src="bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    $('.btn').button()
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
        <label class="btn btn-primary active">
            <input type="checkbox" checked>Option 1 (pre-checked)
        </label>
        <label class="btn btn-primary">
            <input type="checkbox">Option 2
        </label>
         <label class="btn btn-primary">
             <input type="checkbox">Option 3
            </label>
    </div>
 </body>

 </html>
```

Comment: missing jquery? oh yesss

Comment: Please try to include the appropriate jquery version: https://developers.google.com/speed/libraries/devguide#jquery

Comment: Check with your preferred Dev. Tools that javascript dependencies are successfully called.

Comment: `$('.btn').button()` will do absolutely nothing in your posted code.  There are no HTML elements when that method executes.

Comment: My bad, I just noticed that I left to link to jquery out. The problem I am now facing is that of using the mentioned buttons with AngularJS. Is this possible? Think so right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are forgot that Bootstrap have a strong dependency to JQuery set to version 1.9.0 or higher

http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#whats-included

> jQuery required Please note that all JavaScript plugins require jQuery
>   to be included, as shown in the starter template. Consult our
>   bower.json to see which versions of jQuery are supported.

add following script tag before inclusion of Bootstrap js

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: don't forget to add type="text/javascript"

Answer (score 0):

My page was working with CDN links but was not working locally. I even downloaded the same CDN file it still didn't work. My link looed like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
```

Finally, I added  type="text/css to my link and it worked:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css" type="text/css">
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, `rel="stylesheet"` was missing from my `<link />` element.